# How to get total processor time in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, process, cpu-usage

I've researched a lot but all I can find is how to get the a single process time.

```
Process p = exampleProcess
return p.TotalProcessorTime
```

How can I get the total processor time? Will I get the % CPU usage of that process if I perform:

```
return p/totalProcessorTime
```

?

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by 'total processor time' then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`PerformanceCounter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx):

```
PerformanceCounter cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", p.ProcessName);
double currentCpuPercent = cpuCounter.NextValue();
```

Answer (score 2):

Nah, you can't divide a `Process` by a `Timespan`. `TotalProcessorTime` is a measurement of how much time was actually spent executing code.  It is an absolute number. If you want a relative number then you need to measure how long the process has been running. Subtract `StartTime` from `ExitTime`. Like this:

```
Process prc = /* something */
var wallTime = DateTime.Now - prc.StartTime;
if (prc.HasExited) wallTime = prc.ExitTime - prc.StartTime;
var procTime = prc.TotalProcessorTime;
var cpuUsage = 100 * procTime.TotalMilliseconds / wallTime.TotalMilliseconds;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the total processor time, not limited to a single process, correct? Does that mean you want the processor time for all processes on the system? Wouldn't that be the same as the elapsed wall time since the system was started? If so, [GetTickCount64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724411%28VS.85%29.aspx) will do the trick.

Comment: Isn't the CPU time counted for each processor core separately, i.e. if a process is fully occupying two CPU cores the total cpu time would be twice of the actual time elapsed?

Comment: Good point. Then it'd be GetTickCount64 * GetProcessorCount. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470844.aspx